# How to run a batch command when closing a batch script by clicking close button

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, cmd

I am running having a batch script which runs a long running command. I want to run another script when i close the command prompt running the first script using close button.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. CMD do not have any kind of event triggered command. This includes events such as closing its window, moving its window, scrolling its window contents, and mouse clicks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Any other idea like a background process which is started by this script. This process will check if the parent process is alive or dead. some thing like this.

Comment: You'll need to separate the parent and child script in different window (i.e.: via `START` command). Use `TITLE` command to change own window title of parent script to a unique name. e.g.: `ParentBatchXYZ`. Then use `TASKLIST /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq ParentBatchXYZ" /FO CSV /NH` to check presence of the parent script window. This should be done repeatedly (preferably with delay) by the child script or by another script.

Answer (score 0):

Run a secondary cmd in silent mode that will always check the first cmd running with pid. When the first not appear the secondary trigger the require event and run exit cmd to close itself.